# How do I update a value in C# and SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

This is my procedure which should update the score in a table with 3 columns: `id`, `nickname`, `scor`.

`Otherform.id1` is the `id` of the user that needs the update and it's taken from the login form .

```
void update()
{
        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(co);
        c.Open();          

        string up1 = "Update Scoruri Set Scor='" + Convert.ToInt32(scor1) + "' where ID='" + otherForm.id1 + ";'";
        //z.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", scor1);
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(up1, c);
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();          
        string up2= "'Update Scoruri Set scor='" +Convert.ToInt32(scor2) + "' where ID='" + otherForm.id2 + "';'";
        SqlCommand h = new SqlCommand(up1, c);
        h.ExecuteNonQuery();            
        c.Close();
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't tell what is wrong exactly but I see a few things wrong in your code.

- You should always use [*parameterized queries*](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [*SQL Injection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.
- I assume your `Scor` and `ID` columns are numeric, not character. That's why you should not use single quotes with it. With parameterized queries, you don't need to worry about that.
- Use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` adn `SqlCommand`.
- In your second `SqlCommand` (which is `h`) you are executing first command (`up1`) not second one (`up2`).

As an example;

```
void Update()
{
  using(SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(co))
  using(SqlCommand comm = c.CreateCommand())
  {
     string up1 = "Update Scoruri Set Scor=@scor where ID=@id";
     comm.CommandText = up1;
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scor", Convert.ToInt32(scor1));
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", otherForm.id1);
     c.Open();  
     comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
     comm.Parameters.Clear();
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scor", Convert.ToInt32(scor2));
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", otherForm.id2);   
     comm.ExecuteNonQuery();       
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry im pretty nubish in c# right now. my code doesn't update the score in the table. everything works smoothly it just doesn't do anything. i don't know how to use the using statetment but i did the other things you said and it still doesn't work.

Comment: ok , i did all that and it doesn't work . i have a select sql command which selects the initial score , at first i tought that maybe wrong but if i do a messagebox that shows the score , it shows the value i wanted. it just doesn't update well

Comment: @user3401766 I demonstrate an example. Try it. And debug your code first. See all your values are ok. Try your `UPDATE` commands in your management studio first. Look at the values of `Convert.ToInt32(scor1)` and `otherForm.id1`. See they are valid numeric value or not.

Comment: ok i wrote it that way, all the values are int32 and the columns are int type int the table. everything is fine. can it be a problem from the server or db settings? it still doesn't update the score

Comment: @user3401766 What is your command looks like exactly when you debug your code (after adding parameter values)?

Comment: 'using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(co))
            {
                using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(up1, c))
                {

                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scor", scor1);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", otherForm.id1);
                    c.Open();
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    c.Close();
                }' first part

Comment: 'using (SqlCommand h = new SqlCommand(up2, c))
                {
                    h.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scor", scor2);
                    h.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", otherForm.id2);
                    c.Open();
                    h.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    c.Close();
                }
            }
        }' second part. sry but im really just a beginner i started c# only like 2 weeks ago in school and i want to go to the olympiad, i couldnt find what the problem was on any other overflow answers thats why i did a new topic

Comment: @user3401766 **NO!** What is your `comm` looks like before your `comm.ExecuteNonQuery()` line? Debug your code please and tell. And please read some books about sql.

Comment: hmm. i have no error on the code. it debugs smoothly. it just doesnt work

Comment: i think i found the problem and it is a connection with the database problem. after i debug the connection automatically closes.

Answer (score -2):

```
string up1 = string.Format(@"UPDATE Scoruri SET Scor = {0} WHERE `id` = '{1}'", Convert.ToInt32(scor1), otherForm.id1);
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(up1, co);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

try this... using string format.

Comment: Please don't do that. `String.Format` doesn't prevent _SQL Injection_.

Comment: And where this `OleDbCommand` coming from?

Comment: And why you executing your command twice?

Comment: common sense please. its just duplicated.